# trying to run grunt tasks for development and prod mode does not run the default task

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat, grunt-contrib-uglify

I have two modes i.e production and development modes for js and css minification in prod mode and only concat in dev mode.

I have multiple tasks for this and i have set the default mode to development  for some reason, grunt fails saying  task 'development' not found. When i have explicitly defined development in default task.

Here is my gruntfile.js

```
 module.exports = function (grunt) {
     // Load grunt tasks automatically
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // object to represent the type of environment we are running in.
   var EnvType = {
      prod: 'production',
      dev: 'development'
   };

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: require('./package.json'),
    config: {
        // Configurable paths
        app: 'src/main/webapp',
        lib: '<%= config.app %>/lib',
        dist: 'target',
        distApp: '<%= config.dist %>/XXX'
    },
    clean:{
        dist: '<%= config.distApp%>',
        // Remove target folder
        target: '<%= config.dist%>'
    },

    // GENERATE CSS ----------------------------------------------------
    less: {
        development: {
            options: {
                compress: false,
                yuicompress: false,
                optimization: 2
            },
            files: {
                '<%= config.app%>/css/main.css': 'src/less/main.less'
            }
        },
        production: {
            files: {
                '<%= config.app%>/css/main.css': 'src/less/main.less'
            }
        }
    },
    //----------------------Concat CSS files----------------------
    concat: {
        css: {
            src: ['<%= config.app %>/css/ux.css', '<%= config.app %>/css/main.css' ],
            dest: '<%= config.distApp %>/css/style.css'
       },
        js: {
            src : ['<%= config.app %>/js/Utilities.js',
                   '<%= config.app %>/common/**/*.js',
                   '<%= config.app %>/js/**/*.js',
                   '<%= config.app %>/js/app.js'],

            dest: '<%= config.distApp %>/js/core.js'
        }
    },
    //----------------- Minify concatenated CSS stylesheet ------------------
    cssmin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.distApp %>/css',
                src: 'style.css',
                dest: '<%= config.distApp %>/css',
                ext: '.min.css'
            }]
        }
    },
    uglify: {
        js: {
            files: {
                '<%= config.distApp %>/js/core.js': ['<%= config.distApp      %>/js/core.js']
            }
        }
    }
});

/**
 * Utility function to register the stylesheets task to grunt.
 * @param  {[type]} mode  [the mode, either dev, or production]
 */
var registerStyleSheetsTask = function(mode) {
    var styleTask = (mode === EnvType.dev) ? 'concat:css' : 'cssmin';
    grunt.registerTask('stylesheets:' + mode,
        'Compiles the stylesheets for development mode',
        ['clean', 'less:' + mode, styleTask]
    );
};

/**
 * Utility function to register the scripts task to grunt.
 * @param  {[type]} mode  [the mode, either dev, or production]
 */
var registerScriptsTask = function(mode) {
    // if we are running in dev mode, only concat the scripts
    // otherwise minify them also
    var scriptTask = (mode === EnvType.dev) ? 'concat:js' : 'uglify:js';

    grunt.registerTask('scripts:' + mode,
            'Compiles the javascript files in ' + mode + ' mode',
        ['clean', scriptTask]
    );
};

//register tasks for both prod and dev modes
registerStyleSheetsTask(EnvType.dev);
registerStyleSheetsTask(EnvType.prod);
registerScriptsTask(EnvType.dev);
registerScriptsTask(EnvType.prod);

// register development mode as the main task
grunt.registerTask('default', 'Default task: development', 'development');
```

};